# Mongo::Error::OperationFailure, InvalidBulkOperation, BulkWriteError, when inserting JSON document into MongoDB

Tags: ruby, json, mongodb

I am writing a ruby(v. 2.3.0) script to import JSON file into MongoDB(v. 3.0.8). I tried three ways to insert JSON hash into one of the collections on MongoDB, but all the attempts got errors.

1)

**Code:**

```
coll = db.collections(my_collection)
coll.insert_one(json_hash)
```

**Error:**

```
$oid is not valid for storage. (52) (Mongo::Error::OperationFailure)
```

2) Just used `insert_many`, instead of `insert_one`.

**Code:**

```
coll = db.collections(my_collection)
coll.insert_many(json_hash)
```

**Error:**

```
Invalid document format for bulk insert_one operation: ["_id", {"$oid"=>"5786e89f536a733ef63c58e0"}]. (Mongo::Error::InvalidBulkOperation)
```

3) As I have seen these two errors, I thought the problem was with `"$oid"`. So, I removed `"$oid"` from the value that the key is `"_id"` in the JSON file.

**Code:**

```
new_hash = {}
  object.each do |obj|
    obj.each do |key, value|
      if key == "_id"
        value = value["$oid"]
      end
    new_hash.store(key, value.to_s)
  end
end
```

However, after trying to insert `["_id", "5786e89f536a733ef63c58e0"]`, I got

**Error:**

```
Mongo::Error::BulkWriteError (Mongo::Error::BulkWriteError)
```

How could I pass those errors?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by this line.

```
coll.insert_many(json_hash)
```

`json_hash` couldn't be inserted in database directly. It should be wrriten in the given format: [Mongo::Collection#insert_one](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/Mongo%2FCollection%3Ainsert_one).

Finally, I changed the code like,

```
object.each do |row|
  coll.insert_one({name: row[0], lat: row[1], lng: row[2], length: row[3]})
end
```

It worked perfectly.